# Improve performance of find -exec …

Tags: find, performance

I need the list of sub-directories (not files) in a directory so I can pass it to a Java program. So I am using this command to get the list on Linux machine:

```
find /some_directory -depth -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec basename {} \; > listfile.txt
```

And then I pass `listfile.txt` to Java program as an argument. There are some issues to get the list directories from the Java program itself, hence I am doing this. But the above `find` command is taking a lot of time (~ 35 mins) as there are more than 200k files.

Can this be optimized or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Probably Java has bindings to [opendir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), [basename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html), [stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) functions or system calls.... I would use these bindings from your Java program

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To print only file name instead of path, with GNU¹ `find`, you can replace `-exec basename` with `-printf '%f\n'`. Explained in [GNU `find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) man page:

> %f
>
> File's name with any leading directories removed (only the last element).

Also if you want only directories in your output you probably should use `-type d` option:

```
find /some_directory -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' > listfile.txt
```

`-depth` is superfluous as you're only finding files at one depth (1).

<sup>¹ `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` are also GNU extensions, but contrary to `-printf`, they are also found in some other `find` implementations nowadays.</sup>

Comment: What needs to be added to above command to find only those sub directories that start with a particular prefix like "CR-"?

Comment: Use `-name` option, `-name "CR-*"`. For details, see [find man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to store the list of entries except `.` and `..` in the `/some_directory` directory, one per line, that's what the `ls` command, with the `-A` option is for:

```
ls -A /some_directory > listfile.txt
```

That also has the benefit of sorting that list (with GNU `ls`, you can disable the sorting with `-U`).

In your case, it's very inefficient because you're running one `basename` command per file.